# Are dogs permitted on trains in Netherlands?

Tags: netherlands, amsterdam, pets, rotterdam

We will be staying the night in Rotterdam, but may like to visit Amsterdam for the day without taking the car.

We have a medium sized dog (breed: Eurasier, ~25kg) and would like to bring him to Amsterdam. He is not a guide dog, just a regular pet.

We're looking to take the high-speed train.

Any problems with us doing this? Would we need to purchase an additional ticket for the dog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on which trains you're using, as they differ from service to service.

A [full writeup on the various rules](https://www.nsinternational.nl/en/before-you-go/transporting-pets) covers much of this.

I'll try and summarise:

- Sun and Ski Thalys - only guide dogs
- Thalys - small and guide dogs = free in a basket. Bigger dogs = buy a ticket.
- TGV - yes, but must buy a ticket and be in a box or muzzled and on a leash.
- Eurostar - only guide dogs.
- ICE - yes, with exceptions, tickets to be purchased.
- Domestic Netherlands trains - yes, [conditions](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&sl=nl&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ns.nl%2Freizigers%2Fovchipkaart%2Freizen%2Fmeenemen-fiets-huisdier.html&sandbox=1) apply:

> A small pet that fits into a bag or basket or can be kept on your lap
>   may free on the train. For leashed pets you must purchase a Day Pass
>   dog. Regardless of your destination this ticket costs € 3. Note that
>   each rail carrier uses other terms and rules.
>
> If you have an OV-year subscription, you may take one dog free.

Comment: Thank you for the handy summary. The domestic netherlands trains (NS) is most likely the one we will take - however am having trouble finding the conditions for pet travel on the website. Anyone able to find this?

Comment: @killercowuk Can't find an english version (I think the English NS site is just a partial translation of the Dutch one) but [here's the relevant page in Dutch](http://www.ns.nl/reizigers/ovchipkaart/reizen/meenemen-fiets-huisdier.html). It says pets travel for free if they fit in a bag or on your lap. If that's not the case you have to buy a day pass for €3 (price is independent of travel distance). You can buy the pass separately or upload the product too your OV chip card.

Comment: Fyra is like Thalys, buy a ticket.

Answer (score 3):

> Een klein huisdier die in een tas of mand past of op schoot gehouden kan worden, mag gratis mee in de trein. Voor aangelijnde huisdieren dient u een Dagkaart hond aan te schaffen. Ongeacht uw bestemming kost dit kaartje € 3. Let op dat iedere railvervoerder andere voorwaarden en regels hanteert.

Short in english:
A small pet that can be carry'ed in a bag or on your lap can be taken with you free of charge.

For bigger pets (like 25kg dogs) you need to buy a "day ticket Dog", for the whole day you can than take your dog with you where-ever you want. Price for a day ticket dog is said te be 3 euro's.

Source:
http://www.ns.nl/reizigers/ovchipkaart/reizen/meenemen-fiets-huisdier.html

This ticket is also valid for domestic Arriva:
http://www.arriva.nl/klantenservice/veelgestelde-vragen/in-de-bus-en-in-de-trein/

Answer (score 1):

Unless you feel the need to experience the high speed train, that does not get to full speed on that line anyhow, take the regular train.
I would guess you can carry your 25 kg dog in a bag, in which case it is traveling for free on the regular trains. It can walk to the platform, you only have to carry it into the train to fit the rules, and it should sit on or in the bag while in the train.